# How to enable COMPLUS_ENABLE_64bit flag?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, .net

I had a problem with an application running in Windows Server 2008 R2. I found from [IBM's website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398266) that the reason for this problem was that the application was 32bit and Win Server 64 bit. The guidance was:

> Method #2
>
> Modify the 64-bit client device (for example Windows 2003
>   64-bit Citrix/Terminal Server) to automatically run *all* website's
>   .NET code as 32 bit
>
> Steps:
>
> 1. Logon to the 64-bit (operating system)
>      client device as an administrator
> 2. Start - Run "CMD"  (to launch
>      a command prompt)
> 3. Change directory to
>      C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\
> 4. Ldr64.exe setwow
>
> This will disable the "COMPLUS_ENABLE_64BIT" flag and cause *all* .NET
>   code to run as 32-bit on this 64-bit client device.

I would like to know how can I enable this COMPLUS_ENABLE_64BIT again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You repeat the first three steps, then execute Ldr64 with different arguments:

```
Ldr64.exe Set64
```

This will restore the ability to run the 64bit runtime.